# eliminating all the null values and showing all the values in one record

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to make a select statement to table1 so that it looks like table2  oracle. Please help. I tried some case when and pivot but I failed again and again.

table1:

```
Product   abc    def   ghi
1          100   0     0
1          0     10    0
1          0     0     20
2          0     0     80
2          0     60    0
2          3     0     0
```

table2:

```
product   abc    def   ghi
1         100    10    20
2         3      60    80
```

Comment: Is `table1` an actual table, or the result of a failed attempt to get `table2` instead? If so, show us the real starting point; you shouldn't have to go through `table1` to get to `table2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do aggregation :

```
select product, max(abc), max(def), max(ghi)
from table1 t1
group by product;
```

However, the value you have provided with sample data the `sum()` would also work. If, table has `NULL` instead of `0` then both function would work but i would prefer to use `max()` if the `null` values in table.

Comment: `sum` is probably better, since it will work the same for negative values. `max` won't.